# WatchOS App crash after changing display name

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I was building my application and I decided to change the display name. After the change, this error occurred.

```
 2020-06-16 16:16:39.647223-0700 Test App[4270:147334] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:interfaceControllerCreationCompletion:]:3200: Couldn't instantiate class _TtC37Capsule_Controller_WatchKit_Extension17HostingController
2020-06-16 16:16:39.647359-0700 Test App[4270:147334] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:interfaceControllerCreationCompletion:]:3201: Critical failure. Simulating crash: Condition failed:"NO". Couldn't instantiate class _TtC37Capsule_Controller_WatchKit_Extension17HostingController
(lldb)
```

I changed the display name for the app and the extension. If you could help, that would be appreciated.